# Could not load System.Web.Cors in Owin Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net, azure, oauth-2.0, cors, owin

I have a .Net 4.5.1 application using Web API 2 and running in my local Azure Emulator. I have some OWIN components installed and in my Startup.cs file within the Configuration(IAppBuilder app) function I have the following code block and the last line causes an exception:

```
HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfiguration);
app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

This line is causing an exception "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Cors, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies."

I'm having trouble figuring out why NuGet didnt' install this if it is a dependency. Additionally I'm not able to find a corresponding dll already installed to add a reference myself, nor the correct NuGet package to install to provide said dll.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? If so, perhaps you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

This is surely coming cause of your DLL version is different OR DLL is missing on that environment.

Few steps you require to check:

- Cors DLL should be there in your BIN directory [On Azure]
- If it's there then Version of DLL deployed on server and your local both should be same. [You can check in properties]
- If your version of Cors DLL higher on Azure server, compare to local one then you can

> ```
> <dependentAssembly>
>    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
>    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.1" />
> </dependentAssembly>
> ```

Your new version could be your DLL version which are available into the BIN directory.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Microsoft.Asp.Net.WebApi.Cors at nuget? 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors/5.2.2
It's not a dependency for the Cors package because it's for webapi and the only microsoft.owin.cors dependency is on the base microsoft.asp.net.cors (other than the owin packages).

Comment: Good advice given that I didn't note it, but I do have the Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Cross-Origin Support package installed. The version is 5.2.2.

I also have Microsoft.Owin.Cors 3.0 installed http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Cors/

Comment: I am facing same issue.If anybody solved the same please let me know.